# trying to sum total revenue from a specific listing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I asked this question earlier on stackoverflow and codereview, but I didn't give enough info or show enough code. Sorry about that. I'm new to rails (and programming in general) so I apologize for not paying attention to all the requirements.

I have a basic marketplace app with sellers and buyers. Users can create listings and buyers complete orders on the listings.

I want to display some stats on the listings page. I want the total revenue of a specific listing to show on its listing page.

I defined revenue in my order model as follows:

```
def self.revenue
  Order.sum(:amount).to_f
end
```

And I call it with `<%= number_to_currency Order.revenue, :precision => 0 %>`

on the show page of the listing.

Of course, that just shows the total revenue of every completed order and not the revenue of the specific listing, which is what I want. This was just as far as I got, since every thing else I've tried in my order model has not yielded any success.

I tried to find the specific listing by doing below, but I got pretty lost, and didn't know the right way to call for it on my show page.

```
@orders = Order.where(listing: @order.listing) 
@revenue = 0 
@orders.each do |order| 
@revenue = @revenue + order.listing.amount 
end
```

So, in short, I want to be able to find orders of a specific listing, and then loop and add up the price (defined as amount in my db) of each completed order.

My issue is identifying the specific listing. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the handy `inject` method here :)
According to your answer, you want to be able to `find orders of a specific listing and loop and add up the price`

its probably best to wrap this in a model as an instance method since you want to call it on a specific listing.

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base

def revenue
   orders.inject(0) {|sum, order| sum += order.amount.to_f}
end

end
```

You can then set the `@listing` variable in the controller, and call in the view simply as `<%= @listing.revenue %>`

Comment: interesting using the inject method. thanks for the suggestion. i've tried what you mentioned, but i'm getting an undefined method `revenue' for nil:NilClass when i try to view the show file. any guesses why? i've tried looking to see if something was missing in my model or controller, but couldn't identify anything.

Comment: how are you setting the `@listing` variable in the controller? can you share that code?

Comment: sure, do you mean this? `def set_listing
      @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    end`

Comment: and what page are you trying to access? what is the route?

Comment: set_listing seems to be a custom action, just making sure you have the right routing

Comment: i'm trying to view http://localhost:3000/listing/1 as well as a profile:show page that shows a user's listings by username, i.e.: http://localhost:3000/user_name. Sorry, should've mentioned that part as well earlier

Comment: It seems like you are trying to access the 'show' method, so in the listings_controller, make sure in the show method you are setting the `@listing` variable, something like this `ListingsController < ApplicationController def show @listing = Listing.find(params[:id] end`

Comment: yes, I was trying to access show. I tried what you suggested in the ListingsController, but still was given a "undefined method `revenue'" Could there be anything else I may have forgotten to do when creating my revenue variable? Sorry for the trouble, I appreciate your help

Comment: no problem, hmm what seems to be happening is your `@listing` variable is returning `nil` (ie. your database cannot find the listing). Is there a listing created with :id 1?

Comment: yes, i'm sure of it. i tried different IDs of known listings

Comment: hmm seems to be hard for me to debug the problem purely through comments, maybe moving to a chatroom is easier...

Comment: yeah, unfortunately i don't have enough rep to enter a chat room

Comment: i think i may be missing something at the step when you said "set @listing variable in controller" could you maybe elaborate on the step?

Comment: essentially, in the controller you need to set an instance variable by finding the resource with the :id, as mentioned ealrier you'll need some code similar to what you have in your set_listing method above but inside the 'show' method

Comment: OK. yes this is what i had. unfortunately still getting an undefined method after completing all changes you suggested.

Comment: really need a chatroom... any free ones available?

Comment: sorry i should be around now, stepped into a mtg

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each listing and sum the order revenus.

You will need something like this

In you controller you can have the following:

```
@listings = Listing.all
```

And in you show action

```
<% @listings.each do |listing| %>

  <%= listing.orders.sum(:amount).to_f %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm still getting an undefined method for 'revenue'. am i calling for it incorrectly in my show page? i'm saying <%= listing.revenue %>